# I'm got a error in ssis Exception from HRESULT: 0xC001404D & 0xC0014052

Tags: ssis

how to solve this problem in ssis 2005? I'm used script component for validation.

I'm validating each column in script component using VB Script. while import high volume of data more 50 million. If any one column value failed based on my validation script. That time getting following error in ssis (Deadlock detected while trying to lock variables. The locks cannot be acquired after 16 attempts. The locks timed out.)

Public Overrides Sub ValidateColumn_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As ValidateColumnBuffer)
        Try
            Row.IsSkipped = False
            'Declare and set variables
            Dim Var As IDTSVariables90 = Nothing
            Dim str As String

```
        Me.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(Var)
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strEligibilityKeyEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strMemberIDEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strServiceFromDateEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strServiceToDateEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strDxCode1EmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strAllowedAmountEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strPaidAmountEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strPaidDateEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strFacilityIDEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strServiceTypeEmptyMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strServiceFromDateInvalidMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strPaidDateInvalidMsg")
        Me.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::strServiceToDateInvalidMsg")

        'Field length and Expression validation
        Row.RowId = intRowId + 1
        intRowId = intRowId + 1
        Row.IsValidationSuccess = True

        'Required field validation
        'User::strEligibilityKeyEmptyMsg - Eligibility Key is empty !
        If (Row.EligibilityKey_IsNull Or Row.EligibilityKey.Trim().Length = 0) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strEligibilityKeyEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'User::strMemberIDEmptyMsg - MemberID is empty !
        'If (Row.MemberIDClaimantID_IsNull Or Row.MemberIDClaimantID.Trim().Length = 0) Then
        '    Row.IsSkipped = True
        '    Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strMemberIDEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
        '    Return
        'End If
        'User::strServiceFromDateEmptyMsg - ServiceFromDate is empty !
        If (Row.ServiceFromDate_IsNull Or Row.ServiceFromDate.Trim().Length = 0) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strServiceFromDateEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'strServiceFromDateEmptyMSg - Invalid ServiceFromDate ! 
        Dim ServiceFromDate1 As Match = Regex.Match(Row.ServiceFromDate, "^([1][012]|[0]?[1-9])[/]([3][01]|[12]\d|[0]?[1-9])[/]([1-8][0-9][0-9][0-9]|9000)$")
        'Dim ServiceFromDate1 As Match = Regex.Match(Row.ServiceFromDate, "^(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\/(([0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0,9][0-9][0-9]))$")
        If Not ServiceFromDate1.Success Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid ServiceFromDate"
            Return
        End If


        'User::strServiceToDateEmptyMsg - ServiceToDate is empty !
        If (Row.ServiceToDate_IsNull Or Row.ServiceToDate.Trim().Length = 0) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strServiceToDateEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'strServiceToDateEmptyMSg - Invalid ServiceToDate ! 
        Dim ServiceToDate1 As Match = Regex.Match(Row.ServiceToDate, "^([1][012]|[0]?[1-9])[/]([3][01]|[12]\d|[0]?[1-9])[/]([1-8][0-9][0-9][0-9]|9000)$")
        'Dim ServiceToDate1 As Match = Regex.Match(Row.ServiceToDate, "^(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\/(([0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0,9][0-9][0-9]))$")
        If Not ServiceToDate1.Success Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid ServiceToDate"
            Return
        End If

        'User::strDxCode1EmptyMsg - DxCode1 is empty ! 
        If (Row.DxCode1_IsNull Or Row.DxCode1.Trim().Length = 0) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strDxCode1EmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If
        'User::strAllowedAmountEmptyMsg - AllowedAmount is empty ! 
        If (Row.AllowedAmount_IsNull) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strAllowedAmountEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If


        'Placeofservice value more than 2 digits! 
        If Row.PlaceofService.ToString().Length > 2 Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Placeofservice value more than 2 digits!"
            Return
        End If

        'MemberAmount is empty ! 
        If (Row.MemberAmount_IsNull) Then
            Row.MemberAmount = 0
        End If

        'User::strPaidAmountEmptyMsg - PaidAmount is empty ! 
        If (Row.PaidAmount_IsNull) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strPaidAmountEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If
        'User::strPaidDateEmptyMsg - PaidDate is empty !
        If (Row.PaidDate_IsNull Or Row.PaidDate.Trim().Length = 0) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strPaidDateEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'strPaidDateEmptyMSg - Invalid PaidDate ! 
        Dim PaidDate1 As Match = Regex.Match(Row.PaidDate, "^([1][012]|[0]?[1-9])[/]([3][01]|[12]\d|[0]?[1-9])[/]([1-8][0-9][0-9][0-9]|9000)$")
        'Dim ServiceToDate1 As Match = Regex.Match(Row.ServiceToDate, "^(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\/(([0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0,9][0-9][0-9]))$")
        If Not PaidDate1.Success Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid PaidDate"
            Return
        End If

        'User::strFacilityIDEmptyMsg - FacilityID is empty !
        If (Row.FacilityID_IsNull Or Row.FacilityID.Trim().Length = 0) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strFacilityIDEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'User::strServiceTypeEmptyMsg- ServiceType is empty !
        If (Row.ServiceType_IsNull Or Row.ServiceType.Trim().Length = 0) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strServiceTypeEmptyMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If


        'Invalid service Type!
        If (Row.ServiceType.Trim().ToUpper <> "IPS" And Row.ServiceType.Trim().ToUpper <> "IPA" And Row.ServiceType.Trim().ToUpper <> "OPM" And Row.ServiceType.Trim().ToUpper <> "OPS" And Row.ServiceType.Trim().ToUpper <> "ER" And Row.ServiceType.Trim().ToUpper <> "EM" And Row.ServiceType.Trim().ToUpper <> "ANC") Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid Service Type!"
            Return
        End If

        'In case of any char or special char in integer/money/numeric  field, importer must skip those records.
        If (Not IsNumeric(Row.AllowedAmount)) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid char/speceial char is in Allowed Amount"
            Return
        End If
        'In case of any char or special char in integer/money/numeric  field, importer must skip those records.
        If (Not IsNumeric(Row.PaidAmount)) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid char/speceial char is in Paid Amount"
            Return
        End If


        'In case of any char or special char in integer/money/numeric  field, importer must skip those records.
        If (Not IsNumeric(Row.MemberAmount)) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid char/speceial char is in Member Amount"
            Return
        End If

        'User::strServiceFromDateInvalidMsg - ServiceFromDate is Invalid Format !
        If (Not IsDate(Row.ServiceFromDate)) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strServiceFromDateInvalidMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'User::strPaidDateInvalidMsg - PaidDate is Invalid Format !
        If (Not IsDate(Row.PaidDate)) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strPaidDateInvalidMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'User::strServiceToDateInvalidMsg - ServiceToDate is Invalid Format !
        If (Not IsDate(Row.ServiceToDate)) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = Var("User::strServiceToDateInvalidMsg").Value.ToString()
            Return
        End If

        'PaidDate greater then default date ! 
        If (Convert.ToDateTime(Row.PaidDate.Trim()) > Convert.ToDateTime("12/31/9000")) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "PaidDate greater than default dates !"
            Return
        End If

        Var.Unlock()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Row.ErrorDesc = ex.Message().ToString()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stack. Please provide us more information so we can help you!

Comment: Please edit your post when adding information to a topic. Comments are used to request clarification. A) Post your script, we aren't mind readers. B) Is there a reason you must use a script to validate this value? It sounds like a Derived Column Component that generates a boolean value based on your condition of value being greater than 50 million. Then use a conditional split to find erroneous rows.

Comment: The "deadlock detected while trying to lock variables" message sounds like there's an issue with the way the script is trying to access package variables. As @billinkc requested, please update your question with the script so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Use Var.UnLock() before each **Return** in the **If** condition.